# Why is Kubera called dhanadena?

Tags: name, kubera

Kubera is also called dhanadena. It can be seen from [first sarga](https://www.valmikiramayan.net/utf8/baala/sarga1/bala_1_frame.htm) of Bala Kanda of Valmiki Ramayana

> विष्णुना सदृशो वीर्ये सोमवत्प्रियदर्शनः |
>
> कालाग्निसदृशः क्रोधे क्षमया पृथिवीसमः || १-१-१८
>
> **धनदेन** समस्त्यागे सत्ये धर्म इवापरः |
>
> viirye = in valour; vishNunaa sadR^ishaH = comparable to
>   Vishnu; somavat priya-darshanaH = attractive in look like the moon;
>   krodhe = in anger; kaala-agni-sadR^ishaH = matchable to the world
>   ending fire; kShamayaa pR^ithvii samaH = equals to the Earth in
>   forgiveness; tyage = in benevolence; **dhanadena samaH = equal to Kubera**
>   [God of Wealth]; satye = in candour; aparaH = with no rival; dharmaH
>   iva = like Truth personified. [18, 19a.]

What is the meaning of dhanadena and why is he Kubera called so?

Comment: Where have you heard this? Dhanadena means "give money" in Hindi. It means asking to give money. That is not an adjective.

Comment: In Balakanda, Sarga 1, Sloka 18/19... The translation says that it is Kubera... @Sarvabhouma

Comment: @Sarvabhouma Dhanadena means dhana dene wala (giver of wealth) in hindi. Btw it's root is dhanad

Comment: May be the actual word is  Dhana-Deva instead of Dhana-Dena. It could be a mistake :-D

Answer (score 3):

The original word you are meaning is धनद.Dhana means wealth.द comes from the root दा which means giving.So धनद  means bestower or giver of wealth.धनदेन is tritiya bibhakti ekabachana which is used because of the word सम.Its a grammatical tule tells that when sama is used,the one with whom or which comparison is being made should be in tritiya bibhakti.
Lord Kuber is the treasurer of the Gods and also the King of the Yakshas among the galaxy of all Hindu Gods. The very name of Kuber reflects glory, prosperity and wealth combined with abundance. He is the in-charge of all the wealth in the universe.

Here is the link for kuber: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kubera

you get the meaning of धनद as kubera here :[http://sanskritdictionary.com/?iencoding=iast&q=धनद&lang=sans&action=Search](http://sanskritdictionary.com/?iencoding=iast&q=%E0%A4%A7%E0%A4%A8%E0%A4%A6&lang=sans&action=Search)

And you get the grammatical rule here: https://iskcondesiretree.com/group/sanskrith-learning/page/grammar-tutorial-instrumental-case-trritiiya-vibhakti

Comment: Segmentary overview of how the word is composed: https://sanskrit.inria.fr/cgi-bin/SKT/sktgraph.cgi?lex=MW&st=t&us=f&cp=t&text=dhanadena&t=VH&topic=&mode=g&corpmode=&corpdir=&sentno=